# Wordpress: Custom order query (categories)

Tags: wordpress

I am using the latest version of WP, no plugins installed but one (I am talking about it later). For every category I have assigned a featured image and I would like to make a page where every category is shown with its featured image. I have installed the Category Order and Taxonomy Order plugin in order to change the order of appearence of the categories. For example we have the categories 1,2,3,4 and the desired order is 3,1,2,4.

In the functions.php I have put

```
function wptp_add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

in order to have featured images for the categories.

In my page's template I put

```
 $cats = get_categories();
    for_each ($cats as $category)
    {
    if ($category->term_id != 1){
       $terms[] = $category->term_id}
}

$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_status'=>'inherit',
                        'category__in' => $terms,
                      /*'order_by' => 'none' */
                    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
.......
```

The rest is code where I have the output of the "posts". The problem is that ***$terms*** contains the right order (3,1,2,4), ***$query*** does not (4,3,2,1). Even if I put manually the numbers in *'cat'* (in $args), the output order is always the same.
I even created a string from ***$terms*** and used it with *'cat'* but the result is the same.

Is there a way to make a query and the results are in the order I want (not ASC, DESC, or alphabetical, or time-dependent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_categories()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) has as default `order by name asc`
So you just have to replicate that in your array passed to wp_query.
Categories are stored in `wp_terms` table where `term_id` is foreign key to `wp_term_taxonomy`.Here you have a `term_taxonomy_id` which is foreign key to the table `wp_term_relationships`.In this last table you have the `object_id` which refers to the `post_id` in the table `wp_posts`.
So all you have to do is write a custom query to JOIN all those table and replicate the order in get_categories.Something like

```
SELECT wt.name ,wp.*
FROM wp_terms wt JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt 
ON wt.term_id =wtt.term_id  
JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr 
ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id=wtt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.id= wtr.object_id
WHERE wp.post_type = 'attachment' AND post_status='inherit'
AND...
ORDER BY wt.name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem appears in the $query. Even if I put manually the numbers of the categories, it is always ordered in DESC (even if I add "no ordering" ).

Comment: @user1496047 $Query as it is doesnt refer the other tables which contain the named order,your are trying to order by values which are not there